# How to call a method from child component to parent one in vue2?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a child component called `ZimModel.vue` where I created a method `drawGrid()`. I need to call this method in parent component (`mainPage.vue`). The idea is to call this method once the user has finished typing values in input (namely: width of the grid - I added `@input` event to `v-model="inputWidth"`). That's why I also use `setTimeout` with 5 sec delay. However, I have no idea how to 'send' this method up to parent component. I tried with `emit` but I don't think it makes any sense.
I use Vuex store in my app but this particular method is strictly related to other data and methods in `ZimModel.vue` so I don't think it' makes sense to move it to Vuex. Is there any pattern/good practice I should follow in this case?

Here is a reproducible example: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-2-playground-vuex-drag-and-snap-to-tiles-un6984?file=/src/components/mainPage.vue.
As an example I added `myGreeting()` method (in `mainPage.vue`) to show how I want my program to work. I need to replace this exemplary method with target `drawGrid()` method.

Comment: i got little confuse so you wanna call drawGrid() method from parent component?

Comment: Because this method must be called once user stops typing values in input

Comment: My answer works for you or not?

Comment: Yes! But I added a question regarding `setTimeout`, could you take a look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using $ref will solve your issue:

```
<ZimModel ref="zimModel" />
```

And inside your method:

```
triggerDrawing() {
  clearTimeout(this.timer);
  // this.timer = setTimeout(this.myGreeting, 5000);
  this.$refs.zimModel.drawGrid();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I can now pass the method. However, I need to call this method along with `setTimeout`, after 5 sec. I changed to: `this.timer = setTimeout(this.$refs.proj2D.drawGrid(), 5000); ` but method is called without delay, immediately. How to make it work with `setTimeout`?

Comment: I think it should have work anyway it's a method should have work with setTimeout

Comment: Yes, it works, I forgot to remove watcher in my code (some old code), now it's ok. Thanks for support!

Answer (score 1):

Whilst the using `ref` should work, you should consider outsourcing the method to a .js and importing the method in the files you need it. This is especially recommended when using a method in several components.

In the new file:

```
export function drawGrid() {
// Your code
}
```

In your components

```
</template>
<script>
import { drawGrid } from 'relativePath' 
// using {} you can import a single function or few select to improve effectiveness
...
```

Then you can just call the function.